# how to get id from string which ends with certain word (regexp)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

i want to get `id` which is ends with "_theTable" in string using regex. but i am not getting that . i am using this code:-

```
 var str="<table id='dnn_ctl_123_theTable'><tr><td></td></tr></table>";
 var rexexp = new RegExp("\b\w*_theTable\b"); 
 var matchedwrd=rexexp.exec(str);
```

Please guide how to do this?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've answered the RegEx question below, but I'm not sure that tagging an ID with `_theTable` and then using RegEx to find it again is a good approach. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `new Regexp` you have to escape your backslashes like so:

```
var rexexp = new RegExp("\\b\\w*_theTable\\b");
```

Or you can use a regex literal:

```
var rexexp = /\b\w*_theTable\b/;
```

Comment: thanks ..that works fine. i'll accept this as an answer after 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str="<table id='dnn_ctl_123_theTable'><tr><td></td></tr></table>"
var rexexp = /id='(.+?)_theTable'/;
var matchedwrd=rexexp.exec(str);
alert(matchedwrd[1]);
```

Comment: Using `.*` here strikes me as risky. You could wind up with something like `dnn_ctl_123_theTable'><tr id='something else`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str="<table id='dnn_ctl_123_theTable'><tr id='another'><td></td></tr></table>";
var regEx = /id='(.*?_theTable)'/;
var id = str.match(regEx)[1];
document.write(id);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the pattern `id='([^']*)_theTable'` for this. Then `$1` should correspond to the portion of the id before `_theTable`. If you want to include the `_theTable` bit, just move the closing parenthesis after it.

Comment: I am taking all the table on my page using regex and then i have to get id of table, which ends with word "_theTable".